# Cannont load library libflora.dll

Tags: omnet++, flora

I'm working with omnet, first import Inet 4.3 and works, run simulation example from Inet/simulation and works fine, but when import Flora version 1.0.0 after to import build project and run simulation example, this show me the next error.

add picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The latest Flora version on the website is 1.0.0 and it clearly states that works with OMNeT++ 6 pre10. You are trying to build it with 6.0preview14 version of omnet (the latest one). There were several changes in OMNET since pre10 so your build is most likely failing and no wonder you cannot run something that was not successfully compiled. You should either use the exact version numbers the software indicates or wait until FloRa is updated for omnet 6.0pre14.